# how to plot dataframe nest list in group?

Tags: r

I have a directory structure with rasters
like this:
folder absorbance: farm1.tif, farm2.tif
folder resistance: farm1.tif,farm2.tif
They are rasters in geotiff
I have to make comparison graphs between the two farms (farm1 and farm2) for the same type of data (absorbance, resistance).
Farm1 and Farm2 are not stackable, so I don't use rasterStacks
Farm1 and Farm2 can have a different number of cells.

I went so far as to create nested lists of dataframes

````
```
raster_dir <- c(list.dirs(path = cartella,recursive = F,full.names = F))
raster_files <- lapply(raster_dir,function(dir) {
                      raster_files <- as.list(list.files(path=paste(cartella,dir,sep='/'),
                                 pattern = "\\.tif$",
                                 full.names = TRUE,
                                 recursive = F))
                      })
names(raster_files) <- raster_dir
rasters <- rapply(raster_files,rast,how = "list",deflt = NA_integer_)
rast_df <- rapply(rasters,terra::as.data.frame,how = "list",deflt = NA_integer_)
```
> str(rast_df)`
  List of 2
  absorbance:List of 2
    ..$ :'data.frame':  1920 obs. of  1 variable:
  ognibene: num [1:1920] 1 1 1 0.000392 0.000252 ...
    ..$ :'data.frame':  2401 obs. of  1 variable:
  toderici: num [1:2401] 0.000467 0.000565 1 1 1 ...
  resistance  :List of 3
    ..$ :'data.frame':  1920 obs. of  1 variable:
  ognibene: num [1:1920] 1 1 1 0.404 0.211 ...
    ..$ :'data.frame':  2401 obs. of  1 variable:
  toderici: num [1:2401] 0.584 0.706 1 1 1 ...
````

probably the problem is in renaming the nested list
why this doesn't work:

````
```
fun_violin_plot <- function(df) gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x='',y=df[,1])) +
  geom_violin(na.rm = T,scale="count") + 
  labs(x=NULL,y = NULL)
rast_violin_plot <- rapply(rast_df,fun_violin_plot,how = "unlist",deflt = NA_integer_)
```
> Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list.
````

Comment: This is somewhat difficult to debug without a minimal reproducible example. You may want to simplify to debug. Are you able to plot this without starting with the `rapply` call? The `aes(...)` also looks off. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html